# Angular custom validation not working for template-driven form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am trying to create a custom validator that compares control to a specific number for template-driven form but for some reason, I can't get it to work. here's what I did so far

template:

```
<div class="td-c">
          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="quantity-label">
            <input  class="form-control" name="number"
               [(ngModel)]="product.item.quantity"
               [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
               (ngModelChange)="updateProductQuantity(i, product)"
               #quantity="ngModel"
               required
               quantityValidator>
           </label>
           <span *ngIf="quantity.hasError('quantityValidator')">error</span>
          </div>
         </div>
```

directive.ts file:

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, NG_VALIDATORS, FormControl, ValidatorFn, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
@Directive({
  selector: '[quantityValidator]',
  providers: [{
   provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
   useClass: QuantityValidatorDirective,
   multi: true
 }]
})
export class QuantityValidatorDirective implements Validator{
 
 @Input() quantity;
 
  constructor(){
   console.log('hello')
 }
  validate(c: FormControl) {
   return this.quantityValidator(5)(c)
 }
  quantityValidator(itemQuantity: number): ValidatorFn{
   return (control: FormControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
     if(control.value === itemQuantity){
       return null
    }else{
      return {
       isGreater: {valid: false}
     }
    }
     
  }
 }
}
```

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you get any solution to this??

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done by reactive forms. I am not sure why are you using the template-driven forms here. I don't think *quantity.hasError('quantityValidator')* would have a value. There won't be a hasError() method on quantity.

You can simply do it in the *updateProductQuantity(i, product)*.
Declare a boolean variable as *hasError* in the ts file and check the quantity change in the `updateProductQuantity()`. If the validation fails change the value of *hasError* to *true*.

In template use like this,

```
 <span *ngIf="hasError">error</span>
```